# How can I configure TypeScript to use multiple node_modules directories with Webpack DLL plugin?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, node-modules

I use Webpack's [DllPlugin and DllReferencePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/) to build a separate "vendor" bundle that contains all of my main dependencies that don't change very often.

The project structure looks like this:

```
project
  App
    (code and components)
  tsconfig.json
  package.json
  node_modules
  vendor
    package.json
    node_modules
```

I am migrating from Flow to TypeScript. I had configured this in my `.flowconfig`:

```
[options]
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=node_modules
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=vendor/node_modules
```

Right now VS Code is showing lots of errors because TypeScript doesn't know about `vendor/node_modules`.

How can I configure the same thing in `tsconfig.json`, so that TypeScript can find all of these libraries?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do this using the `paths` option under `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "vendor/node_modules/*"]
    },
```

This is equivalent to the `resolve_dirname` settings in `.flowconfig`:

```
[options]
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=node_modules
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=vendor/node_modules
```